# NodeMCU V3 + SD Card with Arduino IDE Not working

Tags: arduino-ide, sd-card, nodemcu

I am trying to connect CATALEX MicroSD Card adaptor to new NodeMCU V3 and PIN configuration are as below,

```
NodeMCU  ---------> SD Card
GPIO13 (D7) ------> MOSI
GPIO12 (D6) ------> MISO
GPIO14 (D5) ------> SCK
GPIO15 (D8) ------> CS
VCC (3.3V) -------> VCC
GND --------------> GND
```

Tested above setup with QuickStart program from SdFat library in Arduino IDE. But it gives error output as below,

```
SPI pins:
MISO: 12
MOSI: 13
SCK:  14
SS:   15

SD chip select is the key hardware option.
Common values are:
Arduino Ethernet shield, pin 4
Sparkfun SD shield, pin 8
Adafruit SD shields and modules, pin 10

Enter the chip select pin number: 15

Disabling SPI device on pin 10
Can't access SD card. Do not reformat.
No card, wrong chip select pin, or SPI problem?
SD errorCode: 0X20,0XFF

SD initialization failed.
Do not reformat the card!
Is the card correctly inserted?
Is chipSelect set to the correct value?
Does another SPI device need to be disabled?
Is there a wiring/soldering problem?

errorCode: 0x20, errorData: 0xff
```

> chipSelect is 15.

Also, I am using SanDisk 16GB Micro SDHC class 4 Memory Card.

I have tried googling with the error but did not find solution. Please help me.

Comment: use the SD library. the esp8266 version. it is a part of the esp8266 arduino package. you can find the examples in IDE Examples menu

Comment: Tried CardInfo program with SD library as well and it gives initialization failed error.

Comment: the adapter has a 5 V to 3.3 V conversion? like this one? https://www.arduitronics.com/product/210/microsd-card-adapter-catalex

Comment: @Juraj: The NodeMCU's SPI pins are 3.3V-ish.

Comment: @yeti, I know and if the SD adapter is 5 V then there is the problem

Comment: @Juraj, Adapter does have 5 V to 3.3 V conversion. I am using same adapter as https://www.arduitronics.com/product/210/microsd-card-adapter-catalex.

Comment: could you provide your code?? @Akshay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SD cards work on 3.3 V, so the adapter has 5 V to 3.3 conversion for power and signal, to connect SD card reader to a 5 V MCU. You can't connect this SD card  adapter to an 3.3 V MCU like the esp8266.

Comment: but I would connect the adapter to 5V pin for a test

Comment: NodeMCU has VIN pin which shows voltage around 4.25 V, can this be connected to VCC of the SD card? Or should I use external 5 V power supply?

Comment: I work with Wemos and there is a 5 V pin.  I thought NodeMcu has it too. I don't know it the Vin of NodeMcu can be used to power devices.

Comment: Thank you, it worked with VU pin of nodemcu which provide 5V supply

Comment: This is brilliant, works as a charm surely. I have just tried it out was facing a similar challenge, though for my case the output voltage on VIN is 4.75V

Answer (score 1):

If you are giving power to nodemcu through USB cable. SD card VCC can be connected to the VIN pin of nodemcu ESP8266. I faced the same problem

**NodeMCU V3 + SD Card with Arduino IDE Not working**

but after connecting VCC of SD Card to VIN pin of nodemcu. it worked.

Thanks for the helping me Mr. Juraj